# SVN dumps folder occupied majority of server storage

Tags: svn

I've configured a SVN server for my projects. Also, I've scheduled hotcopy backups. after years, I'm running out of storage. Majority of server storage is occupied by dumps folder.

Can I move dumps folder to another PC for back-up? And, moving dumps folder doesn't make any problem for SVN server?

Comment: Do you really use `svnadmin hotcopy`? Why do you say *dumps* when referring to these backups? Or do you use `svnadmin dump`?

Comment: you're right, I'm using weekly full backup schedule.